# Ajax error within Manage Catergories

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax

Hello When clicking on manage categories and then clicking a sub category. 
None of the data is loading up in the forms as seen below

[image: Screen shot admin interface]

So Checking in network console, I found this error below
[image: Ajax error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found and fixed the issue. 
The issue was down to using the Comodo Mod security rule set. After changing to Owasp its rectified the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be some kind of restriction on your server, rejecting the Ajax request.

This post can help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554935/ajax-403-forbidden-when-making-ajax-request

Has any changes been made to your server environment, specifically related to apache, and mod_security?

Something to try, and determine if it is specifically AJAX issue, is to grab those urls from the console, and remove the isAjax=true form the end, and see what happens if you request them directly,

Comment: Just changed the mod security rule set from comodo to owasp and working fine now..
Thanks for your help